# Frame Width and Height didnt Change on OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm a newbie at openCV and try to set the frame width and height but size of frame didn't change.

Did I miss a set up / something else?

I used my default camera with this code

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3,1280)
cap.set(4,720)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you: https://techoverflow.net/2018/12/18/how-to-set-cv2-videocapture-image-size/

> Note that most video capture devices (like webcams) only support
> specific sets of widths & heights. Use uvcdynctrl -f to find out which
> resolutions are supported:

You can always resize the image manually:
https://www.tutorialkart.com/opencv/python/opencv-python-resize-image/